# Error: incomplete type when using HMAC_CTX in C++ project

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I am trying to compile this library  [ndn-cxx](https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cxx)
in my laptop. I already tried in another computer and it compiled successfully but now i am getting this error and i think its related somhow to openssl. I verify that i have openssl in my laptop using *sudo apt-cache search libssl | grep SSL* and the result is :

- libssl-ocaml - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL (runtime)
- libssl-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL
- libssl0.9.8 - SSL shared libraries
- libsslcommon2 - enterprise messaging system - common SSL libraries
- libsslcommon2-dev - enterprise messaging system - common SSL development files

**The error I am getting when trying to compile the library is :**

```
../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp:49:12: error: field ‘m_context’ has incomplete type
   HMAC_CTX m_context;
            ^

../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp: In constructor 
‘ndn::security::transform::HmacFilter::Impl::Impl()’:
../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp:35:20: error: ‘m_context’ was not declared in this scope
     HMAC_CTX_init(&m_context);
                    ^

../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp:35:29: error: ‘HMAC_CTX_init’ was not declared in this scope
     HMAC_CTX_init(&m_context);
                             ^

../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp: In destructor ‘ndn::security::transform::HmacFilter::Impl::~Impl()’:
../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp:40:23: error: ‘m_context’ was not declared in this scope
     HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&m_context);
                       ^    

../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp:40:32: error: ‘HMAC_CTX_cleanup’ was not declared in this scope
     HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&m_context);
                                ^

../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp: In member function ‘ndn::security::transform::HmacFilter::Impl::operator HMAC_CTX*()’:
../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp:45:13: error: ‘m_context’ was not declared in this scope
     return &m_context;
             ^

../src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp:46:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   }
   ^
```

Comment: What operating system and gcc version are on the successful computer and the unsuccessful laptop?

Comment: `HMAC_CTX` is a public data structure. Ensure `#include <openssl/hmac.h>` is present in the problematic source file. If the include is present, then we need to know where your copy of OpenSSL is located, and how you configured your project. OpenSSL 0.9.8 is really old and its past EOL. But its `<hmac.h>` includes `HMAC_CTX`. Are you on an OS X machine?

Comment: @PaulH. I am using ubuntu 14.04 in both laptops and gcc version 4.8 and they are both located  in the same place /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: @ilyaslahmer - Ubuntu 14 has OpenSSL 1.0.1, and its lib name is `libssl.1.0.0` (IIRC). How is it you are using `libssl0.9.8`? Anyway, make sure the `ssl-dev` package is installed. That's OpenSSL header files.

Comment: Did you try running `sudo apt-get install build-essential libcrypto++-dev libsqlite3-dev libboost-all-dev libssl-dev` to make sure you have all the dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

The [file that causes the compilation error](https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cxx/blob/master/src/security/transform/hmac-filter.cpp) contains the line `#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x1010000fL` and uses the struct `HMAC_CTX` in that case. For newer versions of OpenSSL (>1.1.0), it uses `HMAX_CTX *`. My conclusion is that the `waf` build tool includes the wrong file to get the `OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER` and consequently compiles as if you are using an older version of OpenSSL, with the struct `HMAC_CTX`, which is no longer available as such in the newer versions.

You could do `grep OPENSSL .waf-tools/openssl.py` and analyse the printed lines to see where the different OpenSSL includes come from.